# Licensing requirement for usage of win32com APIs through python package (pywin32)

Tags: licensing, python

For my project work testing, I want to use win32com APIs through python package (pywin32). Is there any license restriction for this? OR in other words what is the license clause if this python script is used to test a commercial development?

There are two aspects:

1. Usage of win32com APIs (of course running machine has valid Microsoft softwares)
2. Usage of python package (pywin32). On https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/ it mention as "OSI Approved :: Python Software Foundation License" for pywin32. But I am not sure if this allows to use in creating scripts to test commercial product and if internally allows Microsoft license.